# How can I implement mathquill in ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, mathquill

I'm building a latex editor using ace editor. I need to support math functions inside the editor as inline. User must be able to enable/disable math mode by pressing (shift + $). After pressing the key he must be able to write math functions and it must render properly inside the ace editor.

Comment: Oh boi if you can I would like to know too